# Netsuite - How do I filter Item search on multiple records

Tags: javascript, filter, netsuite, suitescript

I'm writing a client script in which a it uses Item's internal id and Location's inventory location id for dropdown selection. I want to get the 'quantitypicked' of an Item which is in the Inventory Count records. How do I do this in a Search Filter using the Item's internal Id?

```
var filters = new Array();
      filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'inventorylocation', null, 'anyof', location );
      filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', item);
      //filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('item', 'inventorycount', 'anyof', item);
var columns = new Array();
      columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantitycommitted');
      columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantityonhand');
      columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantitybackordered');
      //columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('quantitypicked');
```

The commented lines is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this is not a field available on the item record. You could calculate it via a search -

```
var search = nlapiSearchRecord('itemfulfillment', null,
    [
        ['status', 'anyof', 'ItemShip:A'], 'AND',  //  ItemShip:A = Item Fulfillment:Picked
        ['item', 'anyof', item], 'AND', 
        ['location', 'anyof', location],
    ], 
    [
        new nlobjSearchColumn('item', null, 'GROUP'), 
        new nlobjSearchColumn('quantity', null, 'SUM')
    ]
);
```

Comment: so I found a solution, I used a join in the columnSearch using columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('quantitypicked', 'transactions');